# Making a tree structure using forking in C

Tags: c, tree, fork

I have been stuck on this for days. I have to write the following tree structure using the fork() function. Any suggestions? This is what I have so far:

Code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   main ()
   {
  int pid;
  pid = fork();
  //Child
  if (pid == 0){
  if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
  {
  printf("GrandChild: child pid = % d, my pid = %d, parent pid = %d \n",
                      pid, getpid(), getppid());
  }
  }
  exit(0); }
```

tree structure:

```
         A
   B           C
D            E   F
```

Comment: And what did you manage to code so far?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry. I added the code now.

Comment: Please take the time and format your code correctly.

Comment: Also, further explain exactly what problem you're trying to solve, as that tree structure is less than clear.

Comment: B and C are the children of A, D is the left child of B, and E and F are the children of C.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should create the tree structure you desire. Each process forks its' children, runs some desired code, and then waits for any / all child processes to finish running:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define printPID printf("my pid = %d, parent pid = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

void fork_error() {
  perror("Failed to fork.");
  exit(1);
}

void fork_child(void (*f)()) {
  int pid;
  if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    f();
    wait(NULL);
    exit(0);
  } else if (pid < 0) {
    fork_error();
  }
}

/* Function prototypes */
void A(), B(), C(), D(), E(), F();

void A() {
  fork_child(B);
  fork_child(C);
  /* Code for A goes here */
  printPID;
  wait(NULL);
}

void E() {
  /* Code for E goes here */
  printPID;
}

void F() {
  /* Code for F goes here */
  printPID;
}

void C() {
  fork_child(E);
  fork_child(F);
  /* Code for C goes here */
  printPID;
}

void D() {
  /* Code for D goes here */
  printPID;
}

void B() {
  fork_child(D);
  /* Code for B goes here */
  printPID;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  A();
  return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
$ ./a.out
my pid = 17365, parent pid = 14178
my pid = 17366, parent pid = 17365
my pid = 17369, parent pid = 17367
my pid = 17368, parent pid = 17366
my pid = 17367, parent pid = 17365
my pid = 17370, parent pid = 17367
```

If you also need child PIDs in each node / process, then have fork_child() return an int containing the child PID.